# Django Form does not load MultipleChoiceField data from ajax POST request

Tags: python, django, ajax, forms, multiplechoicefield

I ve a weird issue with a **MultipleChoiceField** that does not return the items that are in the POST *QueryDict*

here is the Form

```
class TranslationLanguagesForm(forms.Form):
    languages = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={"novalidate": "",}),
        choices=languages,
        required=False,
    )
```

the View is something like (shortened):

```
class AjaxSpotlerCreateView(View):
    def post(self,request):
        # ...
        # some code before
        #
        translation_form = TranslationLanguagesForm(
            self.request.POST, prefix="translation"
            )
        if translation_form.is_valid():
            translation_languages = translation_form.cleaned_data.get(
                "languages"
                )
        #
        # some code after
        #
```

I won't write the whole template but the html created by the form fits what I expected:

```
<select name="translation-languages" novalidate="" class="form-control " id="id_translation-languages" multiple=""> 
<option value="fr">french</option> 
<option value="en">english</option> <option value="es">spanish</option> </select>
```

The jquery that sends the data trough ajax request is given below:

```
function ajaxPOST() {
  var dismiss = false;
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: ajaxURL,
    data: getFormData(),
    beforeSend: function () {},
    success: function (data) {
      $target.find(".modal-content").html(data);
      if (data.length == 0) dismiss = true;
    },
    complete: function () {
      if (dismiss) hideUploadModal();
      else showUploadModal();
    }, //complete
  }); //ajax
}

function getFormData() {
  const result = {};
  const $form = $target.find("form#video-loader-form");
  const $inputs = $form.find("input, select, textarea");
  $inputs.each((_, element) => {
    const $element = $(element);
    const type = $element.attr("type");
    const name = $element.attr("name");
    if (name && type == "checkbox" && $element.prop("checked"))
      result[name] = $element.prop("checked");
    else if (name && type != "checkbox") result[name] = $element.val();
  });
  return result;
}
```

the issue is that the form is never "filled" by the data of request.POST and translation_languages receives always an empty list.

...but `self.request.POST.getlist("translation-languages[]")` returns the correct values

It only happened on *MultipleChoiceField* whereas *ChoiceField* returns the correct value

here are the POST data (you see more data than needed by the form with the issue because there are 4 forms and 1 formset in the view) :

> <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
> ['bQQzHTR4JDFZFnmO1ExlPZhqURHswXTmXA9RGC2c05pBM63ns2gnVwUnbnwGzor1'],
> 'transcription-language': ['en-us'], 'translation-languages[]': ['fr',
> 'es'], 'spotlers-TOTAL_FORMS': ['1'], 'spotlers-INITIAL_FORMS': ['1'],
> 'spotlers-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'spotlers-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'],
> 'spotlers-0-url':
> ['https://test-dev-s.storage.googleapis.com/uploads/FR/5e24512/2021/1/9fccac26/9fc37a26-2545-434f-8bd2-0afc3df839aa_full.mp4?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=storage%40funky-tower-264412.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20210108%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20210108T125533Z&X-Goog-Expires=3600&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&x-goog-signature=8e737cbc384fab5e11002cbc5e6308'], 'spotlers-0-id': ['9fc37a26-1893-434f-8bd2-0afc3df839ef'],
> 'spotlers-0-name': ['ultraclimb'], 'spotlers-0-duration':
> ['00:02:43'], 'spotlers-0-is_postedited': ['true'],
> 'keywords-keywords': [''], 'glossary-glossary': ['']}>

It seems also that the dict returned by ajax POST creates a weird name for multiselect. The name of the field is postfixed by array symbols : []...
So I got `'translation-languages[]': ['fr', 'es']` instead of having `'translation-languages': ['fr', 'es']`

Answer (score 0):

well finally I got it !

the problem was in the way I have built the POST data in the jquery.
I created a dict by collecting all inputs fields names and values but it returned a querydict with a wrong field name for array by postfix it with brackets.

I should rather use `$form.serialize()`
I've made that change and it's now working as expected

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you can set the `traditional` parameter to `true` to the ajax call. This way, jQuery will use `jQuery.param(yourObject, true)` instead of simply `jQuery.param(yourObject)`.

You keys referring to list of values will not be altered.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (see at the **data** settings explanation)

Cheers,